# Nutella nougat very oily

Tags: baking

I’m making a Nutella-based nougat and noticed that it’s very oily. Does anyone have any ideas as to why and how to mitigate this?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the site! In order to get an answer you will need to edit and add your recipe and method.

Comment: First, I assume you are referring to the hazelnut based nougat more common in Northern Europe, not the Southern European version which is an entirely different confection also called nougat. Second, hazelnuts already do contain a lot of oil, nutella contains hazelnuts plus a lot of extra oil (and sugar). Please provide a recipe but I suspect your ingredients just have a very high fat content.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [confectionery emulsifier](https://www.ingredientsnetwork.com/47/resourcefile/10/17/57/Chocolate%20and%20confectionery%20emulsifiers%20-%20by%20Palsgaard.pdf), which reduces oil separation might help.

Failing that, instead of using Nutella, add hazelnut butter into the ganache.  If the nut-butter has no emulsifiers, it will separate on its own - so some of the (delicious) excess oil could be removed before use.

It's also possible to buy nut powders, but these may cause textural issues.